# Get name of class another class is instantiated inside of in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

Is it possible to get the name of a python class in another class that was instantiated inside the first class.

Let me give you an example.

```py
class SubClass:
    top_level_name = None # name class it is instantiated in e.g. TopLevelClass

class TopLevelClass:
    subclass = SubClass()
```

I understand that I can write the following...

```py
class SubClass:
    def __init__(self, class_name):
        self.top_level_name = class_name

class TopLevelClass:
    subclass = SubClass(class_name)

    def __init__(self):
        self.class_name = self.__class__.__name__
```

However, it would be nice to do it without needing to pass the class name as an argument when the class is initialized.

Is this possible, just wishful thinking, or a really bad idea for some reason I have not thought of yet.

Comment: As I understand you want to know inside which class is given class instance created ?

Comment: @Take_Care_ Yes. That is what I would like to do.

Comment: So there are two ways that I can think of :  first -> https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__

Comment: Second ->  meta-class, because the class itself is just an instance of some metaclass, the metaclass can implement special initialization like the one you need.

Comment: "However, it would be nice to do it without needing to pass the class name as an argument when the class is initialized." But that would be the most straight-forward and explicit way to do this. You *can* do what you are proposing, but it would probably involve instrospecting the call stack and all other sorts of metaprogramming which would be completely overengineering something for little apparent gain (indeed, it would be *worse* from my perspective, non-idiomatic and non-explicit "magic"). It would also probably be hard to create a robust solution.

Comment: In your example, `subclass = SubClass()` *isn't being instantiated inside of a class* - that code is part of a block that will be executed to *produce* a class, but at the actual time of execution `TopLevelClass` does not exist yet.

Comment: Thank you @Take_Care_ that was what I was looking for.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Your points are well taken. Thank you! If it were not for `__set_name__` as Take_Care_ pointed out I don't think I would tried to build a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest revisiting the design for these two classes. Having the instantiated class be aware of the calling class violates design principals of encapsulation and abstraction. It also creates a cyclic dependency (in this case only a logical dependency as only the name of the class is known). If you're using the class name as some kind of identifier for the instantiated class, you can pass in an id string in the constructor as you have in your example.